# Time limit exceeded. Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решаю я значит [задачу](https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8-3373/step/7?course=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Python&unit=956) на Stepic. И у меня возникла проблема. Вроде как задача простейшая, написал код, который при моей проверке на рандомных значениях выдает все нормально. А вот Stepic выдает ошибку Failed test #3. Time limit exceeded. Может кто разбирался с этой задачей, или прсото сможет понять, в чем дело. Код прикреплю ниже на всякий случай

```
a = {}
r = int(input())
for i in range(r):
    x = int(input())
    a[x] = f(x)
    print(a[x])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По условиям задачи функция f(x) вычисляется очень долго, чтобы пройти тест нужно кэшировать результат выполнения и если на вход приходит значение x которое уже вычислялось, нужно брать значение из кэша.

Вы кэшируете резальтат, но никак не используете закэшированный ответ.

Comment: Благодарю. Буду пытаться это осуществить

Comment: Все исправил. Спасибо, спасаешь мою пятую точку уже второй раз ;)

Answer (score 0):

Считайте, что функция f(x) уже определена выше. Определять её отдельно не требуется.

```
d = {}
for i in range(int(input())):
    k = int(input())
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = f(k)
    print(d[k])
```